# Who was the first to make use of the joke "You mean, when are we?"

Tags: time-travel, history-of, trope

There is a very common joke in time-travelling stories. One person asks "Where are we?" and the other responds, "You mean, when are we?".

What is the earliest instance of this joke being made? I am specifically excluding literal "when are we?"'s without the context of the joke.

Comment: I don't get it. What is the joke?

Comment: @user14111 It's not where are we, it's when are we. Gravity Falls has a great take o it during the time travel episode (don't remember which)

Comment: Your definition of a "joke" must be different from mine. For me, "it's not what you know, it's who you know" is not a joke, "it's not the heat, it's the humidity" is not a joke, and "it's now where are we, it's when are we" is not a joke. The only "jokey" thing about it is that "when are we" is not exactly normal English, but that's still the case if "when are we" is used all by itself. But O.K., I think I understand the question. You're simply looking for the first instance of the exchange: A. Where are we? B. When are we?

Comment: @user14111 Sci-fi writers think it's a joke. It's extremely common, and many people here are familiar with it. I don't think it's that funny either, but it is a joke.

Comment: @user14111 I agree with TheAsh that it's usually played as a joke. The person saying "when are we" is not seriously correcting the grammar of the other, but is making a tongue in cheek remark that they have been displaced through time but not necessarily through space.

Comment: The earliest print instance I could find through a Google Books search is *Weet* by John Wilson in 1995: "'I think a better question would be: when are we?' replied her brother" [Link](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=T72qbOlEhcgC&dq=%22when+are+we%22+%22time+travel%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22when+are+we%22). That said, since this is 1995, I have my doubts this is truly the first instance. The line does strike me as something likely to arise on TV where the quip is more characteristic. It may be difficult to find as transcripts of pre-1995 shows are spotty.

Comment: @called2voyage That would be a passable answer, as no one has made a serious attempt at answering it yet

Comment: It's time travel, so therefore it's irrelevant who was 'first'...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**1919**: The earliest usage I've come across is in "[The Runaway Skyscraper](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54832)" by Murray Leinster, originally published in *Argosy and Railroad Man's Magazine*, February 22, 1919, republished in [*Amazing Stories*, June 1926](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v01n03_1926-06/page/n59/mode/1up).

> Arthur was still pursuing his investigation when a sob from Estelle made him stop and look at her.
>
> "Oh, what *are* we going to do?" she asked tearfully. "What are we going to do? **Where are we?**"
>
> "**You mean, *when* are we**," Arthur corrected with a grim smile.

So it's being expressed with a gallows humour, but still an element of humour.

Just for fun, I did find that the [*International Code of Signals*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=yiHHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA86&dq=%22when+are+we+?%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVvtaOpKHtAhWYGlkFHSVIAvMQuwUwAHoECAQQBw#v=onepage&q=%22when%20are%20we%20%3F%22&f=false) from 1909 lists "CQX = When are we?" so it's possible that some captain in the 19th century had to deal with this question too. :)

Comment: Thank you for finally answering this question! I will award you a bounty.

Comment: Wow - how did you find that?! Impressive.

Comment: @tardigrade I used a time-bounded Google books search for "when are we" restricting the search to 1900-1940; several pages in I got a hit on a magazine compilation that looked promising and spent a bit of time chasing it down - ultimately it was "Arthur corrected with" that got me to the actual quote.

Comment: If you limited the search to start in 1900, how do you know it wasn't used prior?

Comment: @FreeMan Because I wasn't asked to list all the ways I _didn't_ find it?  I only described the successful search.

Comment: Leinster was so ahead of his time.